# Graph theory question about dual

Tags: graph-theory

We have a G graph, already drawn to planar. This G graph has only triangles as territories.
We have the dual graph of G too, and this graph only has tetragons as territories.

Is there any graph with the following attitude, and if yes, how many edges and vertices does it have?

Answer (score 3):

Use Euler's formula: $V - E + F = 2$.

Since $G$ has only triangles as territories, $3F = 2E$.

Since the dual of $G$ has only tetragons (quadrilaterals?) as territories, every vertex of $G$ has degree 4. So $4V = 2E$.

You should now be able to determine the number of edges and vertices.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** consider the graphs of the Platonic solids.